# Declaring string for if statement

Tags: c#, string, winforms, if-statement, declare

I have checkBox1 and I need to make a string depending that checkBox1 state.

When checkBox1 is not checked I need:

```
string[] myString = {"1","2","3"};
```

And if checkBox1 is checked I need:

```
string[] myString = {"a","b","c"};
```

I have tried to use if statement

```
if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
    string[] myString = {"a","b","c"};
}
else if (!checkBox1.Checked)
{
    string[] myString = {"1","2","3"};
}
```

Problem is that `myString` is declared in if statement so I can not use it afterwards. I don't know how to declare `myString` before if statement so that I can modify it in if statement.

Comment: Declare myString before if/else, then do myString = new string[] {values}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare `myString` only once

```
string[] myString = null;

if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
    myString = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
}
else
{
    myString = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
}
```

Comment: You can even leave out the `string` keyword when you assign: `myString = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };`.

Answer (score 2):

Make you `myString` declaration outside if statement for making it global

```
string[] myString;

if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
    myString = new string[]{"a","b","c"};
}
else if (!checkBox1.Checked)
{
    myString = new string[]{"1","2","3"};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You declare it outside the `if` statement by leaving out the assignment part:

```
string[] myString;

if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
    myString = new string[]{"a","b","c"};
}
else if (!checkBox1.Checked)
{
    myString = new string[]{"1","2","3"};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is  declare same variable  in two times and variable not define in public scope . try this  one .. as seem else if is  not necessary in your requirement because i  removed  that

```
string[] myString = null;

    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        myString = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
    }
    else  
        myString = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
    }
```